# Adjust the window size with the text length in it with tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Do you know if it's possible to adjust automatically the width of the window to match the length of the text in it?
For example the [image: picture 1] fits well, but in the [image: picture 2] the text get out of the window.

Or if better, is it possible to do line break to fit the text in the window?

PS: to insert the text in my window I am using a `ttk.Label()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the `wraplength` attribute of the label

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
tk.Label(root,width=40,text="This is going to be far too long to fit on the screen that I have chosen").grid()
tk.Label(root,width=40,wraplength=100,text="This is going to be far too long to fit on the screen that I have chosen but will wrap").grid()

root.mainloop()
```

The behaviour seems a bit inconsistent to me but it should wrap at 40 characters.

Answer (score 2):

if you dont want to explicitly set the size of the window to a specific size then you can do

```
window.geometry("")
```

and it will automatically resize to fit the content of the window

Comment: Yes but the thing is that I also need to know the width and height of the window to place it at the center of my screen, with your solution it will just pop up in the right corner. But just for the text to fit, it works.